# LineTraceSingle Collision Not Working (Unreal Engine 4)

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm having quite a difficult time trying to use `LineTraceSingle` to detect a hit.

```
void ACustomActor::Tick(float DeltaTime){
    bool isHit = world->LineTraceSingle(HitResult, start, endV,
            traceParams, FCollisionObjectQueryParams(ECC_WorldStatic));
}
```

My understanding is this is sending out a line from the starting point to the ending point and trying to discover the first "block" (hit) event from an object of type `WorldStatic`.

I am drawing a debug line with the following code:

```
    DrawDebugLine(GetWorld(), start, endV, FColor::Blue, true, 1.0F, (uint8)'\000', 5.0f);
```

**This is working, and I can see my line going through a wall.**

[image]
[image]

As you can see above, the object type of this wall is indeed `WorldStatic` and it blocks all collisions.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Answer**

`world` needs to be `GetWorld()`

---

### **Explanation**

I was saving a reference to the UWorld* pointer in my Actor's constructor, like so:

```
MyActor::MyActor()
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    world = GetWorld();
}
```

***The problem is `GetWorld()` returns NULL here!*** I'm surprised there wasn't any errors thrown actually...
To prevent this from happening this call should be somewhere else, like `BeginPlay()`:

```
void AForceField::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    world = GetWorld();
}
```

But once I actually looked up `GetWorld()`, I saw it was a "*getter for the cached world pointer*". So there's really no point in saving that to a variable.

---

### **TL;DR**

Don't save `GetWorld()` to a variable.